# Is there a way to run an insert into statement with a valid "?" in it?

Tags: special-characters, teradata, insert-into

I am trying to build an insert into statement that will include a URL string which has a valid "?" in it.  I am using Teradata SQL Assistant (Windows XP) and it is trying to translate this into a parameter.

Is there any way to override this and treat it as a character value?

Example URL:
https://www.location.com/livelink.exe?func=ll

Comment: did you try encoding the "?" into its html friendly form? That way you should be able to use the insert into statement and when used in the address bar, it will work as well

Comment: I just tried that.  the URL does not work when it is encoded.  I get a "windows cannot find" error.

Comment: hm, well did you try decode when you fetched the result back? use the same encoding format which will give you what was there earlier.

Comment: Can you post the SQL you are using that SQL Assistant is having trouble processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the **Query** tab on the `Tools -> Options...` page and uncheck the box labeled "Allow use of Named Parameters in queries".  Here are the settings I use:

[image: Sreeen shot]

That will prevent question mark from being treated as prompts and process an insert statement like this:

```
insert into yourdb.yourtable
  (url)
  values ('https://www.location.com/livelink.exe?func=ll')
```