# Teradata escape characters in a string

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some query to match a URL address, but the URL contains a special character '?' which I don't know how to escape.

the query is like:

```
select *
from table
where url = 'www.someaddress.com/**?something**=sth';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Used paramaterized queries to avoid having to escape characters and avoid SQL injection problems.  Examples: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/

Comment: If you're using SQL Assistant, you can [disable named parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477671/is-there-a-way-to-run-an-insert-into-statement-with-a-valid-in-it).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ESCAPE.

```
where url = 'www.someaddress.com/**?something**=sth';
```

would be

```
where url = 'www.someaddress.com/**@?something**=sth' ESCAPE '@';
```